# display managerNames and EmployeesNames from employees table

Tags: sql-server

[image: the two tables from my DB]

I need to return two values from  [empname] in (the EMPLOYEES) table 
which displays

**empname** in a column --- and ---

their **managersnames** (empname) in the other column

which there is  no managername in departments

when i write this code it returns blank values

```
select empname managername, deptname 
from employees , departments 
where departments.managerid=employees.empid
and
employees.empname ='arwa'
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? which one? please tag the DBMS you are really use.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I think you're missing a comma between `empname` and `managername`.  Without the comma, you're aliasing (renaming) `empname` as the literal text 'managername', not the column value.  Also, is this homework?  If so, you can add that tag

Comment: That query will not work because you are join to departments on the manager id but you also said only get the one row for 'arwa'. You need the employee information first, then join to departments, then to employee again.

Comment: @Beth there is no column in the data named managername so it could only be an alias. Of course they should be more explicit about aliases.

Comment: i added managername after empname as an alias

Comment: @mahmoudsamir Make sense, that's why I like to use `AS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try starting with

```
select *
from employees 
where empname ='arwa'
```

you'll see `arwa`'s `deptID` is 3.  You want to add `deptID` 3's `employeename` aliased as `managername`

so next join in your `departments` table:

```
select
  e.*, managerID
from
  employees e inner join 
  departments d on
  e.deptID = d.deptID
where empname ='arwa'
```

you'll see `arwa`'s department `managerID` is 7.  You want to add `managerID` 7's `employeename` aliased as `managername`. Try:

```
select
  e.empname , m.empname as managerName
from
  employees e inner join 
  departments d on
  e.deptID = d.deptID inner join
  employees m on
  d.managerID = m.empID
where e.empname ='arwa'
```

Comment: hope it helps you understand the process and what's going on.  If this is the correct answer, please accept it, and if it was helpful, you can upvote it.

Comment: Remove the where clause to view all employees.

Comment: remove the `where` clause entirely, then you should see all manager names for all employees.

Comment: if this is homework, you can include that tag, and hopefully the answers will step you through the concepts you're supposed to be learning

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. Also, be more explicit in your aliases to avoid accidents. This query should get you the data you are looking for.

```
select EmployeeName = e.empname
    , DepartmaneName = d.deptname
    , Manager = man.empname
from employees e
join departments d on d.deptid = e.deptid
join employees man on man.empid = d.managerid
where e.empname = 'arwa'
```

Comment: Oops had an extra predicate in the last join. Should be good now.

Comment: was wondering about that, why would the manager's `deptID` have to be the same as the employee's `deptID`?  In this case, though, it shouldn't have excluded any results, because both the employee and manager are in dept. 3

Comment: Yeah that was just odd...happens when we don't have any sample data to actually work with. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
select e1.empname, e2.empname as Manager from employees e1
join departments on e1.deptid = departments.deptid
join employees e2 on departments.managerid=e2.empid
where e1.empname = 'arwa'
```